# Sqlite.swift: how I can use column aliasing(AS statment) after join for decoding?

Tags: swift, sqlite, decodable, sqlite.swift

I want to decode the result of query to my model that I used it in my remote request but after join i cant decode with codingKeys because sqlite.swift replaces the double-cotation and it can't find the column name

my code to get data from sqlite table:

```
let questions = Table("questions")
let replies = Table("replies")
        
let id = Expression<Int64>("id")
let questionId = Expression<Int64>("question_id")
              
let query: QueryType = questions.join(replies, on: questions[id] == replies[questionId])

let rows = try! db.prepare(query)
let values: [MyModel] = try rows.map({ try $0.decode() })
```

MyModel:

```
struct MyModel: Decodable, Identifiable {

var id: Int
var questionText: String
var replyText: String


enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id = "questions.id"
    case questionText = "questions.text"
    case replyText = "replies.text"
}


init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.id = try! container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
    self.questionText = try! container.decode(String.self, forKey: .questionText)
    self.replyText = try! container.decode(String.self, forKey: .replyText)
}
}
```

But I faced with this error:

```
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: No such column `"questions.id"` in columns [ "\"questions\".\"id\"", "\"questions\".\"text\"", "\"replies\".\"text\"", "\"replies\".\"question_id\""]
```

Comment: `case id = "question.id"`, isn't the table name "questions"?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks, but in code, it is correct